# Using a variable as upper bound of a summation (varA = sum(i$(ord(i)<varA),X(i)))

Tags: gams-math

I need to consider "traffic time" in different period of time as a parameter in a VRP problem, so the equation becomes like this:

```
varA = sum(i$(ord(i)<varA),X(i)) + other terms
```

Is it possible to write such a code? Can GAMS or any other software handle such a constraint?

[The equation:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nfnj.png)

Comment: Are you saying you need "traffic time" to be a parameter that changes over time, i.e., you want something like `traffic_time[t]` where `t` is the time period?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: This constraint does not make sense. If $k$ is in the "for all", why is it in the second sum? How is one to interpret the limits of summation in the last sum? What do the superscripts $T$ mean? But the larger question is, where are you stuck? What question, specifically, still remains after the answer below?

Comment: thank you so much, may be I should think on think on it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with GAMS syntax, but in AMPL you would do something like this:

```
set T;                  # set of time periods
param traffic_time{T};  # traffic time in each time period
```

Then you would refer to the traffic time parameter like `traffic_time[t]` for `t in T`. I'm sure there is something similar in GAMS. It might be called something like "parameter indexed by a set".

Comment: I think I need more help pls!  
suppose we have this:
f(x) = summation X  that x starts from zero to f(x)
the problem is the upper bound of summation which is exactly the same as function

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. It would help if you write it out algebraically instead of in words. If this question is separate from your question about how to index a parameter with a set, then you might want to post it as a separate question.

Comment: I attached the equation as image.